# Django Atomic Transaction and TransactionManagementError

Tags: django

I have a view where I want to:
 1. save a model instance
 2. possibly save more model instances

If 1 or 2 has any issues, then roll back both 1 and 2.

Whether I use transaction.savepoint() or I use nested transaction.atomic() calls I end up getting a TransactionManagementError.

#### View - Using transaction.savepoint()

```
@transaction.atomic
def my_view(request):
    foo = Foo()
    sid1 = transaction.savepoint()
    foo.save()
    if foo.whatever:
        error = 'blah'

    sid2 = transaction.savepoint()
    foo.create_saved_instances()  # creates more saved Foo instances in a separeate func
    if foo.something_else:
        error = 'baz'

    if error:
        transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid1) 
    else:
        transaction.savepoint_commit(sid2)

    ...
```

#### View - Using transaction.atomic()

```
@transaction.atomic
def my_view(request):
    foo = Foo()

    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            foo.save()
            if foo.whatever:
                error = 'blah'

            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    foo.create_saved_instances()  # creates more saved Foo instances in a separeate func
                    if foo.something_else:
                        error = 'baz'
                    if error:
                        raise ValidationError
            except ValidationError:
                pass

            if error:
                raise ValidationError
    except ValidationError:
        pass

    ...
```

### Tracebacks

I get a TransactionManagementError using either transaction.savepoint() or transaction.atomic()

#### Below is the traceback for transaction.savepoint()

```
File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File ".../lib/python2.7site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "...//project/users/decorators.py" in func
  64.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File ".../lib/python2.7site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  184.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ".../project/employers/views/shiftcal.py" in my_view
  238.             transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid1)

File ".../lib/python2.7site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in savepoint_rollback
  66.     get_connection(using).savepoint_rollback(sid)

File ".../lib/python2.7site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in savepoint_rollback
  328.         self._savepoint_rollback(sid)

File ".../lib/python2.7site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in _savepoint_rollback
  288.             cursor.execute(self.ops.savepoint_rollback_sql(sid))

File ".../lib/python2.7site-packages/djangodb/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File ".../lib/python2.7site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  59.         self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()

File ".../lib/python2.7site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in validate_no_broken_transaction
  429.                 "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "

Exception Type: TransactionManagementError at /my-view/
Exception Value: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

#### Below is the traceback for transaction.atomic()

```
Traceback:

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File ".../project/users/decorators.py" in func
  64.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  184.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "../project/employers/views/my_view.py" in my_view
  178.                         foo.create_saved_instances()

File "../project/jobs/models.py" in create_saved_instances
  2685.                     foo.save()

File "../project/jobs/models.py" in save
  2364.         super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  700.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  728.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  812.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  851.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1060.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  59.         self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()

File "../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in validate_no_broken_transaction
  429.                 "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "

Exception Type: TransactionManagementError at /my-view/
Exception Value: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

What is a way I can roll back all transactions and not get a TransactionManagementError?

Comment: What is the traceback for the code that uses `atomic`. I don't think you should be manually raising `IntegrityError`, try raising a different exception instead.

Comment: In the end I have to return a HttpResponse(some_error, status=status) for ajax - I am manually raising the error if I create one, so that can easily pass that error back out, rather than returning an error dict (there is a form in my view as well...it gets a bit messy)

Comment: @Alasdair - I added the traceback for transaction.atomic - thanks.

Comment: @Alasdair yep - I was actually using ValidationError - there is a form in there but I didn't want my example to be too confusing :). Changing to use ValidationError doesn't change the error or traceback

Comment: @Alasdair this only seems to come up if there would otherwise be an integrity error - e.g. i am trying to save an instance that is not unique - even then that is not always true

Comment: The traceback shows that the error is occurring in the `create_saved_instances` method, but you haven't shown the code for that. Is there code in that method that should be wrapped in an atomic block?

Comment: @Alasdair - good stuff. Looking into create_saved_instances further showed that we had a try... except IntegrityError capturing statement and wasn't raising any error, just swallowing it. I have it working now. Thanks

Comment: @Alasdair Trying to understand the logic of this... that IntegrityError has to not get trapped by another method/function being called from this function. Otherwise subsequent functions trying to save in the same transaction.atomic() block or even another method/function are going to raise this TransactionManagementError... I think.

Comment: It looks like you figured it out. You can catch the integrity error inside the `create_saved_instances` method if you want, but if you decide to do this, you should wrap the `new_instance.save()` inside another `transaction.atomic()` block. This idea is explained in [docs for atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) (see the example code and the note).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was in foo.create_saved_instances()

```
def create_saved_instances():
    try:
        new_instance.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

Because of this, the IntegrityError wasn't propagating back to the nested transaction.atomic() call

```
try:    
    with transaction.atomic():
        foo.create_saved_instances()
```

So further writes were attempted in foo.create_saved_instances(), thus raising a TransactionManagementError.

Props to @Alasdair for his assistance